# Pan and zoom a custom svg map without geojson or topojson using d3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js, zooming, pan

As the title describes i am trying to do the same with this bin: https://jsbin.com/cewicolipo

But instead of a topojson i have a SVG from illustrator. I tried a lot but i couldn't get it to work properly.

My attempt looks like this

```
 var width = 800,
    height = 800;

d3.xml('assets/world.svg', (data) => {

  d3
    .select("body")
    .node()
    .append(data.documentElement)
  
    
    let zoomStuff =  d3.select("#gElem")
    let svg2 = d3
      .select("#svgMap")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .call(d3.zoom()
        .on("zoom", function () {
          console.warn('zoom');
          
          zoomStuff.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
        })
        .scaleExtent([1,2])
        .translateExtent([[0,0],[width,height]])
      )
      .append("g")
```

P.S I want the SVG container to be full width and height of the window and also the user to not be able to pan out of the boundaries

Comment: Do you need `d3` for anything else in your project? If not, I'd suggest using [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/). It supports SVG import, pan and zoom. Demo: http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-5

Comment: No i don't use the `d3` anywhere else  right now, but also i don't see anywhere an example with pan limiting in fabric.js after a quick look